# Fold array of arrays efficiently in Python

Tags: python, arrays, performance

I have a dataset that looks like this

```
array([['Sentence: 1', 'Thousands', 'NNS', 'O'],
       [nan, 'of', 'IN', 'O'],
       [nan, 'demonstrators', 'NNS', 'O'],
       ..., 
       ['Sentence: 2, 'To', 'TO', 'O'],
       [nan, 'the', 'DT', 'O'],
       [nan, 'attack', 'NN', 'O']], dtype=object)
       ...,
       ['Sentence: N, 'To', 'TO', 'O'],
       [nan, 'the', 'DT', 'O'],
       [nan, 'attack', 'NN', 'O']], dtype=object)
```

My goal is to transform this into an array of sentences, where each sentence is an array of words. The first value of each subarray indicates if it's a new sentence. The result would look like this:

```
array([['Thousands', 'of', 'demonstrators', ...],
       ...
       ['To', 'the', 'attack', ...],
       ...
      ]
```

I've tried the following so far, which solves the problem but my solution feels inefficient.

```
result = []
current_sentence = []
for row in sentences.values:
    if isinstance(row[0], float):
        current_sentence.append(row[1])
    else:
        result.append(current_sentence)
        current_sentence = []
        current_sentence.append(row[1])
print(len(result))
```

It feels like it should be possible to use some sort of fold operation, but I can't figure out how to do that in Python 3. Efficiency to me in this case is both code compactness and clock time. Any neat ideas?

Comment: Are you using `numpy` arrays here? If you want efficiency, don't use `numpy` arrays with `dtype=object`, which you are here with strings...

Comment: It is indeed numpy arrays. I've loaded the data from csv using pandas and then used df.values to get it into numpy array format. Will try to figure out how to get the appropriate types. Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga!

Comment: If the only reason you are using `pandas` is to read a csv, I suggest just parsing with the built in `csv` module.